# Which C# note shall the tenor sax produce when nothing is pressed?

Tags: saxophone, tenor

Currently, I am practicing the left hand notes on my tenor sax and I noted a sharp difference between the A and G. Using cleartune app I discovered that I jump a whole octave and I don’t produce consistent notes.

For example let’s take the free-hand sound, I noted that I produce C#3 or C#2 in unexpected manner.

My question is which one is correct when I press nothing and what are the tips and tricks to produce a consistent sound ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no keys pressed you should be producing a C#2. A C#3 should only come out if you are pressing the octave key. If the note is jumping between C#2 and C#3 you are you are biting too hard or doing something else wrong, or your instrument is leaking. It's impossible to tell without seeing you play.

Here's a link to a good [introduction](https://tamingthesaxophone.com/saxophone-embouchure) to the saxophone embouchure. And [another one](http://thevault.musicarts.com/saxophone-embouchure-tips-for-beginners/).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but let me ask how to detect if my instrument is leaking ?

Comment: @ShadyAtef Only an experienced player or a repair shop will be able to tell you that, but I think it's more likely you are doing something wrong